# Method is called from my TestMethod only when running in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I'm writing Unit test cases in Visual Studio 2008. I'm facing a weird problem.

From my TestMethod I'm calling a library method. This method is being called when I debug the TestMethod, but when I run the TestMethod this method is not being called.

I checked the references of the dll's, they are perfecly intact.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Regards,
ArunDhaJ

Comment: How do you check the method is called or not? is there specific output you check?

Comment: The method does an variable initialization which is used by the program. When I debug, this variable is getting initialized, but when I run, am getting null pointer exception when accessing that variable...

Please help me, I'm still breaking my head in this... :(

Regards,
ArunDhaJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope!!! I found the way out. Actually I have enabled the code coverage. When I enable it I was using the solution in one path which later copied to some other path. While copying I forgot to change the dll referenced for code coverage, it was refering the old path. This is why when I debug its using the local copy, but when I run, it is using the old dll's. When I updated the reference it is working like charm... :)

Thanks a lot for your support.

Regards,
ArunDhaJ